# Insert values into database by using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I get values in array for one parameter which is width.

HTML file

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div>
```

After I submit values I get only one record in db for width, other variables are all the same except for width which is different.

this is php code

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $width  = $_POST['width']; 
    $quantity =   $_POST['quantity'];
    $length =  $_POST['length']; 
    $productID =  $_POST['productID'];

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i");

    foreach ($width as $value) { 

        $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testDB (width, quantity, length, productID)                 
        VALUES (:witdh, :quantity, :length, :productID) "); 

        $stmt->bindParam(':witdh',$value);
        $stmt->bindParam(':quantity',$quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(':length',$length);
        $stmt->bindParam(':productID',$productID); 

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "success";
            exit();
        } 
        else{
            print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); 
        }  
    }   
}
```

Comment: is the spelling correct ... witdh or width ???

Comment: are the spaces in your html correct ? "width []" should be "width[]"

Comment: @Oops it is width, sorry I was wrong when typing

Comment: Although it may be misleading.  The typo doesn't really matter as it's consistent between the SQL statement and the bindParam call.

Comment: The bind which sets the quantity in the SQL only ever uses the value `$quantity`, as this doesn't change in the loop, it will always be the same for each record.  The only value which is different is the width field.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "success";
        exit();
    }
```

This will execute the prepared statement and if it succeeds (even in the first time around the loop) it will exit the code!

You should also prepare the statement before the loop, so use...

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testDB (witdh, quantity, length, productID)                 
    VALUES (:witdh, :quantity, :length, :productID) "); 
$stmt->bindParam(':witdh',$value);
$stmt->bindParam(':quantity',$quantity);
$stmt->bindParam(':length',$length);
$stmt->bindParam(':productID',$productID); 
foreach ($width as $value) { 

    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "success";
    } 
    else{
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); 
    }  
}
```

You can set a flag to say if anything fails, how you handle this is up to you.

Comment: This is not wrong, but not part of his current problem. He got the name wrong.

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit, even if the name is corrected, they will still only get 1 record.  It's a case of having to fix 2 problems to get it working.

Comment: I think the exit() is just there to test.

Comment: @Rahul, still not sure as one of the problems is that OP says that the other fields don't change (I think) which as they aren't changed means they may be expecting something else.  Have to wait and see.

Comment: Then, OP has to figure out by 'emself.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for helping, the only problem in your solution is that if I enter 2 widths in input fields, it inserts 3 records in database. Last width is 0, is there a way to prevent that. According to amount of entered widths, it should insert that number no all

Comment: 0 must be coming with the other values, you can easily check `if ( $value != 0 ) {` and only run the `execute()` inside this if.

Comment: $width= array_filter($width, 'strlen'); I did it this way and it works

Comment: You might find that `$width= array_filter($width);` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove space from name input element.

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div> 
<div class="col-sm-2"><input type="number" name="width[]" class="form-control"></div>
```

If you check, I removed space from the name after width.

If will give proper output in `print_r($_POST['width']);`

EDIT: Please remove `exit();` as it is stopping the loop after the first insert.

Comment: I made mistake when I was typing. I got an array with values, but each widh should be new record in table. I got only one record

Comment: if you are getting `$width` multiple values, then there is no problem going forward.

Comment: The edit portion which is basically saying what I answered 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @Rahul exit was problem.I have three places to enter width, if I only enter 1 width it inserts three rows in database ? How I can prevent that

Comment: Replace your`$width  = $_POST['width'];` with `$width  = array_filter(array_map('trim',$_POST['width']));` and check